# How to create a function to access JSON index in node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am working with node-red and I would like to create my custom function to access some index from the incoming message. The incoming message looks like this

```
{ "node": "02010101", "base64": "Cro=" }
```

It comes out from the json function block in node-red (*A function that parses the msg.payload to convert a JSON string to/from a javascript object. Places the result back into the payload*), I can use the debug block to obtain the index *base64*, however if I try to do the same with my own function to proces that later, I cannot and I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_msgid' of Cro=
```

My function is really silly for now it is just

```
return msg["base64"];
```

I understand that it complains that there is no property in the incoming message, so I would like to access to hat index, how can I do it?

EDIT: if I set the debug block to show the whole message object not just the msg.base64 itself, I get this

```
{ "node": "02010101", "base64": "Cro=", "_msgid": "6babd6e.f945428" }
```

[image]

Comment: Update the question with a screen shot of the flow so we can see where things are attached.

Comment: This is likely to take more back and forth than Stack Overflow really allows. I suggest you raise this on the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red). If possible include an exported version of the flow that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function node should return a whole msg object not just a string.

If you want to just send on the string value you should do something like this:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload["base64"];
return msg
```

Comment: Hi @hardlib, I get an error in that way `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_msgid' of Cro=`

Answer (score 0):

THe solution was easy, just return the whole message and not just a field. Using the following snippet made it work.

Getting decrypted module

```
msg.payload = msg.decrypted;
return msg;
```

base64Decode

```
msg.payload = msg.base64;
return msg;
```